# Shading editor doesn't have nodes

Tags: node-editor, shaders

[image]I'd like to start adding a world node, but the "add nodes" button is replaced with a weird pin. What do i do?

Answer (score 2):

In the top left corner of the bottom window, notice how there's a dropdown menu labelled *Object*? Click on that and select *World*.

[image: Drop down menu location]

Comment: aw thank you so much! I appreciate it!